# Restrict/Move the context-menu (right click) in window bounds

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi, contextmenu

Whenever you right click at the edge of the browser(or any other application), the context menu will overflow the window, but not the screen.

I want the context menu to always lie in the window bounds, so when I click near the bottom edge it should show the menu towards the top. Assume that the window's dimensions will always be larger than the context-menus'.

Is this possible to do? if not, is there any workaround?

P.S. I am not building an application window, just a viewer for applications.

[image: Context-menu going out of bounds]

Comment: You can implements your own context menu in HTML with javascript in this case the context menu will be displayed in frame (you can probably use some specialized web components to define your own context menus

Comment: The functionality I am looking for should be more at a system level, wherein I can deal with non browser windows as well.

Comment: What is an "application viewer"?

Comment: @andlabs it's just a video streaming app, which is streaming the application window area, that's why I need the context-menu to be inside window bounds.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`Placement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementproperty.aspx)and [`PlacementRectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementrectangle.aspx) properties of your ContextMenu.

In this example below, I set the Placement property to "Relative" and the Rectangle to x,y coordinates 25, 25. Then, no matter where I click the context menu will appear at 25, 25, relative to the Button.

```
<Button ContextMenuService.Placement="Relative" ContextMenuService.PlacementRectangle="25, 25, 0, 0">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Do this" />
            <MenuItem Header="Do that" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

You could, of course, do some more dynamic calculation of what values to use for these properties, based on the size of the menu and its proximity to the edge.